# Transformation of records 1 column 3 row -> 1 row 3 column

Tags: mysql

First look at below query

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total_record, id, modeller,
  MONTHNAME(completed_date) AS current_month,
  QUARTER(completed_date) AS current_quarter,
  Difficulty,
  YEAR(completed_date) AS current_year
FROM model
WHERE modeller != ''
  AND completed_date BETWEEN '2010-04-01'
  AND '2010-05-31' AND Difficulty != ''
GROUP BY Difficulty,
MONTH(completed_date) ORDER BY
MONTH(completed_date) ASC
```

Results I am getting is

```
Modeller  Month  Year  Difficulty

XYZ       Jan    2010  23

XYZ       Jan    2010  14

XYZ       Jan    2010  15

ABC       Feb    2010   5

ABC       Feb    2010  14

ABC       Feb    2010   6
```

I want result like

```
Modeller  Month  Year  Difficulty

XYZ       Jan    2010  23, 14, 15

ABC       Feb    2010  5, 14, 6
```

My database is MySQL for application I am developing so any help would be greatly appericated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).  I've simplified your fields so you'll need to add the calculations back in, but something like this should do:

```
SELECT modeller, month, year, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Difficulty)
FROM Model
WHERE $conditions
GROUP BY modeller, month, year
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice, the GROUP_CONCAT function is powerfull stuff, and probably is a perfect solution in this case.

But watch out, in big systems this kind of manipulation can belong in the application layer and not in the database queries, maximizing easy of maintenance, re-utilization and reducing dependency in the specific RDBMS.

An alternative (more engineered) wait it to use the DAO pattern. Like documented in http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html

Comment: Database vendor changes are less likely than application code.  MVC reinforces that the application layer should be used for as little decision logic as possible - presentation only.  And the database will scale to larger datasets better than any application code...  Those who claim this is easier to maintain in the application code, are the generally least comfortable with SQL...